# What am I doing wrong: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): setToken is not a function

Tags: typescript, react-hooks, react-typescript

I am new to React and TypeScript and I am trying to get a simple approach running. Nevertheless, it does not work. I always get the error: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): setToken is not a function. Anyone can give me a hint?

**App.tsx**

```
import React from "react"
import './App.css';
import VacationManager from "./VacationManager";
import Login from './Login';

function App() {
    const [token, setToken] = React.useState<string | null>(null);

    if(!token) {
        return <Login setToken={setToken} />;
    }

    return <div className="App">
        <div className="Header"></div>
        <div className="App-Body">
            <VacationManager />
        </div>
    </div>;
}

export default App;
```

**Login.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import './Login.css';

async function loginUser(credentials: { username:string | null, password:string | null }) {
    return (credentials.username === "test" && credentials.password === "test") ? "new_login_state" : null;
}

function Login(setToken: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string | null>>) {
    const [username, setUserName] = React.useState<string | null>(null);
    const [password, setPassword] = React.useState<string | null>(null);

    const handleSubmit = async (e: { preventDefault: () => void; }) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const token = await loginUser({
            username,
            password
        });
        setToken(token);
    }

    return <div className="login-wrapper">
        <h1>Please Log In</h1>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <label>
                <p>Username</p>
                <input type="text" onChange={e => setUserName(e.target.value)}/>
            </label>
            <label>
                <p>Password</p>
                <input type="password" onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}/>
            </label>
            <div>
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>;
}

Login.propTypes = {
    setToken: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

export default Login;
```

After entering username and password, I get the above mentioned error. What I am trying to do, is to pass the setter to the Login component, so that it can update the token status. This is just a very simple example to get started, but nevertheless, I do not get what I am doing wrong.

Comment: **All: It's basically a typo.** @ Tobias - You're passing `setToken` as a prop. Props are passed to your function as the first argument, which is an object. But in your `Login` code, you're expecting it to be the `setToken` function. Instead of `function Login(setToken: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string | null>>) {`, you want `function Login({setToken}: {setToken: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string | null>>}) {`. E.g., `setToken` as a *property* of the object you receive (being destructured in that example).

Answer (score 0):

In the login component, the first parameter is an object with the properties, `setToken` being one of them. You can change to:

```
interface LoginProps {
  setToken: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string | null>>;
}

function Login({ setToken }: LoginProps) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function Login(setToken: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string | null>>) 
{
  const [username, setUserName] = React.useState<string | null>(null);
  const [password, setPassword] = React.useState<string | null>(null);
  const [token, setToken] = useState('');
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).